# Parsing criteria in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Is it possible to parse criteria from string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not giving anyone much to go on, so I'll just have to take a guess at what you're trying to ask...

If you're looking for a simple `criteria.Parse("string here");` then no, I don't such a thing exists.

However, the criteria interface lends itself very well to dynamic creation (in fact, that's its intended purpose). As such, yes, you could write a string parser to create `ICriteria` elements from tokens.

Perhaps if you provide more information on the problem you are trying to solve someone can respond with a better answer.